# How to get the thumbnail of an Android gallery picture, in NativeScript?

Tags: android, nativescript

I understand that Android automatically creates a thumbnail, for every picture taken by the camera. I need to be able to display that thumbnail.

I'm using nativescript-imagepicker plugin to select images. The plugin returns only the size and src of the selected image(s), for instance:

> '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/DSCF2060.jpg'

How could i use this src, to retrieve the corresponding thumbnail(is it even possible?).

The Android API is very confusing for me(not to mention the Java), so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The plugin doesn't support that, you will have to query the [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) for the thumbnail.

Comment: Manoj, can you give me some guidance? I barely understand what is going on in this API. For example this phrase: "The contract between the media provider and applications. Contains definitions for the supported URIs and columns."...

Comment: As I check the plugin, I understood extracting thumbnail from media store might not be possible as the plugin doesn't return the content uri but just the image asset. You may create a thumbnail with thumbnail utils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ThumbnailUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils)

```
export function onGetImageButtonTap(args) {
    let context = imagepicker.create({
        mode: "single"
    });
    context
        .authorize()
        .then(function () {
            return context.present();
        })
        .then(function (selection) {
            selection.forEach(function (selected) {
                const size = layout.toDevicePixels(96);
                const bitmap = android.media.ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selected.android),
                    size, size);
                args.object.page.getViewById("thumbnailImg").src = fromNativeSource(bitmap);
            });
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        });
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=YahMNW)